# Tenant sign up fail : Cloud service Multi-tenant MVC application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-roles, multi-tenant

I'm developping a multi-tenant MVC website. 
I have made already a costum azure website that could sign up multiple tenants Azure directories.

When I try make a multi-tenant **cloud service** with a WebRole, the sign up process of a new tenant fails with the message:

> Access cannot be granted to this service because the service listing is not properly configured by the publisher. (ERROR CODE:1028)

I noticed that the replyUrl of the MVC TenantController for the service application was different (then for the azure website) and I tried to enable the SSL properly but with no succes.

[Building a Multi-tenant Application with Windows Azure Active Directory (Single Sign-on, Graph access and Role based Authorization)](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/aadgraphteam/archive/2013/02/25/building-a-multi-tenant-application-with-windows-azure-active-directory-single-sign-on-graph-access-and-role-based-authorization.aspx)

The solution that I tested was pure generated code from the Visual Studio 2013 'new project' wizard where I choose : **Windows Azure Cloud Service** / 1 WebRole / MVC ( Organizational Authentication , Multiple organizations, Single Sign On read directory data).

Does some one have a solution for this problem ?
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

Run your application on HTTPS with SSL. if SSL is not configured then it will trow an error.